# Pandas dataframe is broken up in groups of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read-csv

I have a CSV file that I need to display on a Tkinter text box. I have everything I need inserted into the text box; however it is broken up similar to how it is displayed in the terminal after printing.

Here is what is being displayed in the text box...

```
                      Timezone (minutes)  Unix Timestamp (UTC)  \
Datetime (UTC)                                                   
2020-01-17T23:48:00Z                -300         1579304880000   
2020-01-17T23:49:00Z                -300         1579304940000   
2020-01-17T23:50:00Z                -300         1579305000000   
2020-01-17T23:51:00Z                -300         1579305060000   
2020-01-17T23:52:00Z                -300         1579305120000   

                      Acc magnitude avg   Eda avg   Temp avg  \
Datetime (UTC)                                                 
2020-01-17T23:48:00Z           1.063262  0.541921  30.155257   
2020-01-17T23:49:00Z           1.005967  0.539037  29.979900   
2020-01-17T23:50:00Z           1.045804  0.535254  29.713417   
2020-01-17T23:51:00Z           1.017389  0.532977  29.416833   
2020-01-17T23:52:00Z           1.030430  0.532688  29.275200   

                      Movement intensity  Steps count  Rest  On Wrist  
Datetime (UTC)                                                         
2020-01-17T23:48:00Z                   0            0     0      True  
2020-01-17T23:49:00Z                   0            0     0      True  
2020-01-17T23:50:00Z                   0            0     0      True  
2020-01-17T23:51:00Z                   0            0     0      True  
2020-01-17T23:52:00Z                   0            0     0      True  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I make it display so that all the columns are right beside each other instead of breaking it up?

Here is my code...

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/20200118/310/summary.csv', index_col=0)

def chart():
    scroll = Scrollbar(frame_right, orient="vertical")
    scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=1, sticky="NS")
    scroll_h = Scrollbar(frame_right, orient="horizontal")
    scroll_h.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky="EW")

    table = Text(frame_right, wrap="none")
    table.insert(END, str(df))
    table.configure(state=DISABLED, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_h.set)
    scroll.config(command=table.yview)
    scroll_h.config(command=table.xview)
    table.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
```

The end goal is to make the data display like a table, where I can scroll vertically and horizontally to see all of the data. Right now when I display all 1000 rows the data is too spread out to be able to understand, the user would have to scroll 1000 lines to see the next three columns.